# How to Build EdgeList from a List

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I've written code to build an EdgeList where each element in the list is a node pair set. For example, given the list with the set of 5 node pairs below, the code correctly produces the undirected edge list {a<->b,c<->d,e<->f,g<->h} and the directed edge list {a->b,c->d,e->f,g->h}.

```
list = {{a, b}, {c, d}, {e, f}, {g, h}};
UndirectedEdge @@@ list
DirectedEdge @@@ list
```

Instead of sets of node pairs, suppose list = {{N1,N2,N4},{N1,N2,N3,N4}}. I would like the code I wrote to now produce the undirected edge list {N1<->N2,N2<->N4,N1<->N2,N2<->N3,N3<->N4} and the directed edge list {N1->N2,N2->N4,N1->N2,N2->N3,N3->N4}. Notice N1<->N2 (and N1->N2) appears twice. I can then run DeleteDuplicates to count repeated edges only once.

Any ideas would be most appreciated!!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Partition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Partition.html).

With

```
n = {{N1, N2, N4}, {N1, N2, N3, N4}};
```

Then

```
DeleteDuplicates@*UndirectedEdge @@@ Flatten[Partition[#, 2, 1] & /@ n, 1]
```

> ```
> {N1<->N2,N2<->N4,N1<->N2,N2<->N3,N3<->N4}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Edmund: Very clever and thank u for sharing your insights!! ... 42,700

Answer (score 5):

```
 (BlockMap[UndirectedEdge@@#&,#,2,1]&/@list)//Flatten//DeleteDuplicates

 (* {N1<->N2,N2<->N4,N2<->N3,N3<->N4} *)
```

Comment: Thank u, user1066. I was unaware of BlockMap ... thank u for sharing your code it really advances learning ... regards ... 42700

Answer (score 5):

```
f0 = Apply[Union] @* Map[Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, UndirectedEdge] &];

f0 @ list
```

[image]

```
f1 = Union @* Map[Splice @ Partition[#, 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, UndirectedEdge] &];

f1 @ list
```

> same  result

Comment: kglr ... u r so gifted ... awesome solns!!

Comment: f1 works in Vers. 13.2, but complains that there are too many arguments to Partition.  Hard to understand why/how it works nonetheless.  Seems useful to understand this since method f1 is fastest.

Comment: @StuartPoss, in version 13.1.0 (and earlier versions) it works without triggering an error message (although the sixth argument is highlighted red by syntax highlighter). If you call  `Partition` with 7 or more arguments, (say, `Partition[Range[10], 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Foo, Bar]`)  the error message says _"Partition called with 7 arguments; **between 2 and 6** arguments are expected"_.  The sixth argument simply replaces `List` as the Head of partition elements; e.g., `Partition[Range[10], 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Foo]`

Comment: It pays to go through ALL of the various signatures of Partition to take advantage of this advanced functionality.  Negative values can produce complicated effects. However, if I use Partition[Range[10], 2, 1, {1, -1}, {}, Plus] it works as you indicate.  If an additional function is substituted for Bar above, say Times, it doesn't.  Sometimes,  one needs to take more than baby steps to follow in the footsteps of giants.  Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

```
f2 = Apply[Union] @* Map[EdgeList @* PathGraph];

f2 @ list
```

[image]

```
f3 = Apply[EdgeList @* GraphUnion] @* Map[PathGraph];

f3 @ list
```

> same result